# behaviorspace setup, go and something in between

Tags: netlogo

I have a model that creates a network and selects seed nodes in the `setup` then runs a contagion process in the `go`. For multiple runs, I would like to avoid regenerating the network. If I create two procedures `full-setup` and `part-setup`, is there a way to make BehaviorSpace do `full-setup` the first time and `part-setup` for all other runs?

I was thinking of something with an `ifelse` on `behaviorspace-run-number` but I don't think I can guarantee that run number 1 is the first one to hit the processors.

Answer (score 0):

If you set simultaneous runs to 1 will assure 1 is the first to hit the processors.

Another method that would still utilize simultaneous runs is to run once by hand save your set with nw extension (or just export-world and import-world) and load it for remaining runs.

Comment: The first will take so much more time to run. I am already doing the second really, the network is imported rather than generated, but a bunch of things happen on it that I also want to avoid redoing. This is why I want to have two different setup routines. But thanks for the suggestions, they are useful for most people with this problem.

Comment: hmm, how about exporting and importing the entire world state with `export-world` and `import-world`? note that I don't actually know if the nw extension supports that, though!

Comment: The one thing I could see that could cause problem with `export-`/`import-world` is if you rely on a particular network [context](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#set-context) being set. Other than that, I think it should work.

Comment: From memory, I need to do a new seed after importing I think because RNG is saved. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, export/import-world saves and restores the RNG state.

Answer (score 0):

How about setup commands like:

```
ifelse count turtles = 0
  [ setup-full ]
  [ setup-partial ]
```

replacing `count turtles = 0` with a more appropriate condition for your model, if needed.

I can never remember the exact semantics of reusing world state from BehaviorSpace run to run, when it works or doesn't.  It's a questionable "feature", anyway, that might go away in future version of NetLogo; see https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/105 .